# Site com áudio MP3 não toca no iPhone

Tags: php, ajax, html5-audio

Tenho um site onde toco músicas MP3 ao clicar no PLAY. No PC funciona perfeitamente, porém no iPhone não toca.

BOTÃO PLAY

```
echo "<a href='#' id='tocar-musica'>
    <input type='hidden' class='nm-musica' value='$consulta[nm_musica]' name='dados'>
    <input type='hidden' class='id-musica' value='$consulta[id_musica]' name='dados'>
    <img src='http://www.meusite.net/images/btn-play-enable.png' id='botao' title='Ouvir música' alt='Play'></a>";
```

AJAX

```
    $(document).on('click', '#tocar-musica', function () {

    id_musica = $(this).find('.id-musica').val();
    nm_musica = $(this).find('.nm-musica').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.meusite.net/play_musica.php",
        data: "musica="+id_musica

    }).done(function(msg) {
        $('#botao').html(msg);
        $('#play').html("<img src='http://www.meusite.net/images/equalizador.gif'><br>"+nm_musica);
    });     
});
```

PLAY_MUSICA.PHP

```
<?php
$musica = $_GET['musica'];
?>

<audio autoplay preload="none" controls="controls">
   <source src="http://www.meusite.net/audio/<?php echo $musica?>.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
   O seu navegador não suporta áudio em HTML5.
</audio>
```

Comment: Mas aparece o player? Você quer que ele reproduza automatica a musica ou você quer clicar no play?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, gostaria que fosse automaticamente, mas pelo que andei lendo o AUTOPLAY não funciona no iOS

Comment: Era isto mesmo que eu estava a dizer, mas tem solução, só preciso saber se o player aparece na tela e se clicando nele a musica toca. Outra coisa que notei é que , por que um ajax apenas para gerar o player?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, usei o Ajax para não mostrar o caminho do arquivo ao passar o mouse sobre ele e porque pretendo inserir um contador de cliques. Na verdade o player não aparece na tela, pois como se trata de uma lista com várias músicas, só mostro um gif de equalizador e o nome da música que está tocando.

Comment: Mas não precisa gerar o player no back-end outra coisa, ao retornar o mp3 o usuário com certeza vai ver o caminho da musica, mas isto é outra historia. Só um min, vou tentar formular algo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, e porque eu também pretendia inserir um contador de cliques. Valeu!

Comment: eu refiz o script em uma página localhost, acessei pelo iphone o ip local `http://192.168.2.149` (ip do meu PC) no Safari, cliquei play e depois cliquei na tela, não abriu o player do iOS, a musica só tocou de fundo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeira dica, sempre use `var` quando for declarar as variaveis, ex: `var variavel = ...;`, deve ficar algo como:

```
$(document).on('click', '#tocar-musica', function () {
    var id_musica = $(this).find('.id-musica').val();
    var nm_musica = $(this).find('.nm-musica').val();
```

Eu não vejo necessidade do Ajax (não vai ajudar muito a ocultar), mas isto não vem ao caso agora. Não é necessário "rendereziar/gerar" o player no `play_musica.php`, gere apenas o caminho:

```
<?php
$musica = $_GET['musica'];
echo 'http://www.meusite.net/audio/' . $musica . '.mp3';
```

O ajax deve ficar assim:

```
function gerarPlayer(path)
{
    path = path.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm, '');//Remove espaços em branco, é equivalente ao String.trim

    return (
        '<audio autoplay preload="none" controls="controls">' +
        '<source src="' + path + '" type="audio/mp3">' +
        'O seu navegador não suporta áudio em HTML5.' +
        '</audio>'
    );
}

$(document).on('click', '#tocar-musica', function () {
    var id_musica = $(this).find('.id-musica').val();
    var nm_musica = $(this).find('.nm-musica').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.meusite.net/play_musica.php",
        data: "musica=" + id_musica

    }).done(function(msg) {
        $('#botao').html(gerarPlayer(msg));
        $('#play').html("<img src='http://www.meusite.net/images/equalizador.gif'><br>" + nm_musica);
    });     
});
```

### AutoPlay no iOS

O autoplay é bloqueado no iOS (e outros sistemas mobiles) por conveniência, ou seja economizar a bateria enquanto navega na internet por exemplo, então o usuário escolhe a hora que quer ouvir a música, clicando no play (mesmo que *delegados* via eventos) nos elementos gerados pelas tags `<audio>` ou `<video>`

Porém é possível fazer o player tocar a musica no momento que usuário navega. Como você está usando jQuery então irei fornecer um exemplo com tal. No momento que você clicar ou fazer uma ação você pode disparar o play da musica, por exemplo:

```
document.addEventListener("touchstart", function() {
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorall("#botao audio"), function (audio) {
        audio.play();
    });
});
```

Com jQuery seria:

```
$(document).bind("touchstart", function() {
    $("#botao audio").each(function() {
        this.play();
    });
});
```

Este exemplo irá procurar se tem um player adicionado, se tiver ele inicia a musica quando o usuário tocar na tela (ação `ontouchstart`).

### Eventos da tag Audio para o javascript:

- `abort` - Dispara quando the loading of an audio/video is aborted
- `canplay` - Dispara quando o navegador can start playing o audio/video
- `canplaythrough` - Dispara quando o navegador pode tocar sem parar por causa de buffers
- `durationchange` - Dispara quando a duração do o audio/video é alterada
- `emptied` - Dispara quando a playlist é vazia
- `ended` - Dispara quando a playlist terminar
- `error` - Dispara quando ocorrer um erro durante o load
- `loadeddata` - Dispara quando o navegador carregou os dados do frame atual
- `loadedmetadata` - Dispara quando o navegador carregar os dados meta de um audio/video
- `loadstart` - Dispara quando o navegador inicia o carregamento de um audio/video
- `pause` - Dispara quando o audio/video está pausado
- `play` - Dispara quando o audio/video está reproduzindo
- `playing` - Dispara quando o audio/video quando roda após a espera de um buffer
- `progress` - Dispara quando o navegador está baixando o audio/video
- `ratechange` - Dispara quando the playing speed of o audio/video is changed
- `seeked` - Dispara quando o usuário termina de mover o seek para uma nova posição
- `seeking` - Dispara quando o usuário começa de mover o seek para uma nova posição
- `stalled` - Dispara quando o navegador está tentando pegar dados meta, mas estes dados não estão disponeis
- `suspend` - Dispara quando o browser não consegue pegar dados da midia
- `timeupdate` - Dispara quando quando a posição do playback é modificada
- `volumechange` - Dispara quando o volume é mudado
- `waiting` - Dispara quando a midia para pois está esperado o buffer carregar

Comment: Valeu Guilherme, vou testar e te falo! Abs

Comment: Tem um erro, nessa linha ao inves de (msg) vc colocou (music)... $('#botao').html(gerarPlayer(music)); Corrige caso alguém queira usar =)

Comment: Nessa linha 
$("#botoo audio").each(function() {, 
seria 
"(#botao audio")?

Comment: Funcionou! Valeu... Abs

Comment: A única coisa é que com o iPhone bloqueado ele fica mostrando o caminho do arquivo na tela, tem como não mostrar isso?

Comment: @Ricardo abre o player quando a musica inicia?

Comment: Não, nem no site nem no browser

Comment: @Ricardo Aonde exatamente aparece este url, você disse na tela. Seria na barra de endereço?

Comment: Cara desculpa, aparece no player do iphone mesmo, tinha entendido se estava aparecendo no player da tag <audio>

Comment: @Ricardo eu vou testar, acho que o player sempre aparece, mas me lembro de ter usado no iPad e o player não aparece, vou testar no iOS8 agora (iphone), assim que conseguir lhe retorno, até mais,

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24144/discussion-between-ricardo-and-guilherme-nascimento).